# Simple command-line password generator

Tags: beginner, haskell, security, random

I'm very new to Haskell, I've read most of [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and played around with some simple things, but this is probably the most 'complicated' bit of Haskell I've written so far. I have an implementation in PHP that does basically the same thing, but it is much much faster.. I'm guessing my bottleneck here is that randomRIO takes a long time to return a value, is there any way to increase the speed, or get an array of values instead of grabbing them one at a time?

That aside, any other tips and/or suggestions about improving my implementation would be very helpful!

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import qualified Data.Map as M

import Text.Regex.Posix

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let helpOnly = "-h" `elem` args
    if helpOnly
        then putStrLn usage
        else do
        password <- generatePassword ("-w" `elem` args)
        putStrLn password
    exitSuccess

usage :: String
usage = unlines [
        "",
        "Usage: [ -w, --with-symbols ] [ -h, --help ]",
        "",
        "By default, generates a 16 character password that does not include symbols.",
        "",
        "-w, --with-symbols  include symbols",
        "-h, --help          print a brief help message"
        ]

symbols :: String
symbols = "!$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:@#~,<.>/?"

randomReplace :: String -> String -> IO String
randomReplace [] subject = return subject
randomReplace (replacement:rs) subject = do
    randomIndex <- randomRIO (0, length subject - 1) :: IO Int
    let hash = zip [0 .. length subject - 1] subject
    (randomReplace rs . map snd . M.toList .  M.insert randomIndex replacement . M.fromList) hash

generatePassword :: Bool -> IO String
generatePassword withSymbols = do
    let passwordLength = 500 -- obviously you wouldn't use 500 as a default here, but I'm just benchmarking
    numDigits <- randomRIO (1, passwordLength) :: IO Int
    digits <- replicateM numDigits (randomRIO (1, 9) :: IO Int)
    numUppercase <- randomRIO (1, passwordLength) :: IO Int
    uppercaseLetters <- replicateM numUppercase (randomRIO ('A', 'Z') :: IO Char)
    p1 <- replicateM passwordLength (randomRIO ('a', 'z') :: IO Char)
    p2 <- randomReplace (concatMap show digits) p1
    p3 <- randomReplace uppercaseLetters p2
    password <- if withSymbols
        then do
            numSymbols <- randomRIO (1, passwordLength) :: IO Int
            symbolsToReplace <- replicateM numSymbols ((randomRIO (0, length symbols - 1) :: IO Int) >>= (\x -> return $ symbols !! x))
            randomReplace symbolsToReplace p3
        else return p3
    if (password =~ "[a-z]" :: Bool) && (password =~ "[A-Z]" :: Bool) && (password =~ "[0-9]" :: Bool) -- we knows symbols are in there since it went last
        then return password
        else generatePassword withSymbols
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question (which seems good to me!) learnyouahaskell.com seems super cool.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes good! it was definitely a great resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Too much `IO`.
- `Text.Regex.Posix` is too much for those simple tests. Why not `any isUpper`, `any isLower`, any `isDigit`?
- Your program ignores `--help` and `--with-symbols` (have a look at [`OptParse-Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative))
- `randomReplace` has too many temporary structures (see below)
- You use `length` too often. Unlike in PHP, it's quite slow (O(n) vs O(1)).

## A short search for bottlenecks

> I'm guessing my bottleneck here ...

Don't guess, measure. Enable profiling to check where you're actually losing time:

```
$ stack install --profile random
$ stack install --profile regex-posix
$ stack exec -- ghc -O2 -prof -auto-all PWGen.hs
$ ./PWGen+RTS -s -p
```

If you don't use `stack`, make sure to enable profiling when you install the packages:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install -p random regex-posix
$ cabal exec -- ghc -O2 -prof -auto-all PWGen.hs
$ ./PWGen +RTS -s -p
```

This is actually fast, but not fast enough:

```
9,420,841,024 bytes allocated in the heap
   6,425,011,808 bytes copied during GC
       1,021,088 bytes maximum residency (2915 sample(s))
          59,672 bytes maximum slop
               4 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     15199 colls,     0 par    1.844s   1.971s     0.0001s    0.0011s
  Gen  1      2915 colls,     0 par    1.188s   1.076s     0.0004s    0.0009s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.953s  (  2.001s elapsed)
  GC      time    3.031s  (  3.048s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    5.000s  (  5.050s elapsed)

  %GC     time      60.6%  (60.4% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,823,470,604 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  39.4% of total user, 39.0% of total elapsed
```

Note: I've changed `passwordLength` to `5000`, since it was too quick with `500`. However, the times above don't give enough information where you actually lose that time. That's what `-p` was for. `PWGen.prof` contains the following data:

```
COST CENTRE                        MODULE                     no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                               MAIN                        59           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                              Main                       119           0    0.8    0.0    99.9  100.0
  generatePassword                 Main                       121           1    0.4    0.1    99.1  100.0
   randomReplace                   Main                       124        5730   69.5   62.9    98.7   99.9
    randomReplace.hash             Main                       125        5728   29.2   36.9    29.2   36.9
  main.helpOnly                    Main                       120           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Almost all memory is allocated in `randomReplace`. After all, you break *both* the map *and* the list apart for every character in `replacement`. That's quite costly. Instead, let's try to stay on a single map as long as possible:

```
-- This is still not an idiomatic version, but better
randomReplace :: String -> String -> IO String
randomReplace rs subject = fmap (map snd . M.toList) $ go rs $ M.fromList $ zip [0..] subject
  where
    l = length subject
    go []     m = return m
    go (r:rs) m = do
      randomIndex <- randomRIO (0, l - 1) :: IO Int
      go rs $ M.insert randomIndex r m
```

What's the big difference? Well, we're not using `length` repeatedly, which is a big plus. `length` needs to traverse the whole list to get its result. Also, we're not switching between lists and maps all the time, which gets rid of all intermediate lists.

Running the benchmark again, we gain the following result:

```
  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.016s  (  0.021s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.016s  (  0.011s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.031s  (  0.033s elapsed)

  %GC     time      50.0%  (32.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,105,396,736 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  50.0% of total user, 47.7% of total elapsed
```

```
                                                                                individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                        MODULE                     no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                               MAIN                        59           0    5.6    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                              Main                       119           0    5.6    0.1    94.4   97.8
  generatePassword                 Main                       121           1   55.6   44.7    88.9   97.7
   randomReplace                   Main                       124           2    0.0   16.4    33.3   53.0
    randomReplace.l                Main                       126           2    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    randomReplace.go               Main                       125        5521   33.3   36.6    33.3   36.6
  main.helpOnly                    Main                       120           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Runtime is down to 0.03s from 5s. Keep in mind that this is for `passwordLength = 5000`. This is 0.6% of the original runtime. I can even crank `passwordLength` up to `100000` and it still takes only 0.7s total.

The reason here is (somewhat) simple. `randomReplace` had a bad asymptoticl complexity. If `n` is the length of `subject` and `k` is the length of `rs`, you get roughly:

```
k                    -- for every character in rs
  * ( n              -- get the length of subject (every time!)
      + n * log(n)   -- create the map
      + log (n)      -- insert a character at a random position
      + 2 * n        -- zip the list and zip it back
    )
```

Compare this to the new version:

```
k * (log (n))        -- for every character insert a character into a map
+ n                  -- get the length once(!)
+ n * log (n)        -- create a map once(!)
+ 2 * n              -- zip the map and zip it back
```

So this would be a way to improve your runtime tremendously.

### Further places for improvement

`generatePassword` is too opaque, it's not clear what you're doing. Try to split it into several sections. For example, all those lists of symbols can be abstracted into

```
randomListOf :: Random g => Int -> (g, g) -> IO [g]
randomListOf n r = do
    l <- randomRIO (1, n)
    replicateM l $ randomRIO r

-- ...
generatePassword = do
    -- ...
    digits    <- randomListOf passwordLength ('0','9')
    uppercase <- randomListOf passwordLength ('A','Z')
```

However, you should try to make all your functions pure. That way, you can easily test them later.

Also, you can try to generate passwords that contain at least one digit. It's not possible with random by default, but you can probably achieve something similar to a modified `Test.QuickCheck.frequency`.

Comment: wow, incredible review -- thanks so much for taking the time! I didn't know about the profiling options available, that's incredibly useful -- I'll also definitely be using optparse-applicative from now on, work on simpler abstractions, and making my Haskell code more idiomatic by example.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing my bottleneck here is that randomRIO takes a long time to return a value, is there any way to increase the speed, or **get an array of values instead of grabbing them one at a time**?

Yes there is a way, and not only it is way faster, it is also way simpler:

```
randomsUpTo :: R.RandomGen g => g -> Int -> [Int]
randomsUpTo seed max = map (`mod` max) $ R.randoms seed
```

This just gives an infinite list of random numbers up to a max given an initial seed.

Generating a password is now trivial:

```
randomPassword seed len charset = map (charset !!) randomIndexes
  where
    randomIndexes = take len (randomsUpTo seed (length charset))
```

Benchmarking with:

```
allAscii = map C.chr [32..127]

main = do
  seed <- R.newStdGen
  let x = randomPassword seed 100000 allAscii
  print $ x
```

Takes \$0.27\$ seconds to run.

Running your code for `10000` (that is 10 times less what I ran my code with) took \$95\$ seconds.